# QMessageBox Yes, No, close

Tags: qt, qmessagebox

First I have a QMessageBox and I would like hide the red cross (close). 
I tried with the WindowFlags but I didn't manage.

Secondly, this QMessageBox can't be closed by the user but it can be closed by the code. And when it is closing I wouldn't like it execute the code on the answer No (or Yes).

Comment: Yes, I tried with setWindowFlags(Qt::Dialoq | Qt::WindowCloseButtonHint) and the solution on : http://www.qtcentre.org/threads/41269-disable-close-button-in-QMessageBox. I think, I will do my own messageBox, and resolve the two problems in same time.

Answer (score 0):

Don't you need to turn off the WindowCloseButtonHint? So something like

```
mbox.setWindowFlags(mbox.windowFlags() ^ Qt::WindowCloseButtonHint);
```

If you can get away with using the standard functionality with something like this then it's less code to go wrong and less to maintain for you.

Comment: My QMessageBox is a Qt::tool so I tried messageBox.setWindowFlags((Qt::WindowFlags)(Qt::Tool ^ Qt::WindowCloseButtonHint)); but it doesn't work.

Comment: Did you try it by getting the existing window flags and XORing with WindowCloseButtonHint as above?

Comment: Yes, I tried this : messageBox.setWindowFlags((Qt::WindowFlags)(messageBox.windowFlags() ^ Qt::WindowCloseButtonHint)); but it doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

This works:

```
// Remove Window Close X icon
msgBox.setWindowFlags(Qt::WindowTitleHint | Qt::FramelessWindowHint);
```